# parsing a date string from FTPClient.getModificationTime()

Tags: java, android, ftp-client, date-parsing

I am trying to parse a date string which is a modification date of a file on FTP server. Following is the code.

```
String dateString = mFTPClient.getModificationTime(PDF_FILE_NAME_PS);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

Date modificationDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf(" ")));

Log.v(TAG, "inside downloadservice dateString="+dateString);

Log.v(TAG, "inside downloadservice modificationdate="+modificationDate.toString());
```

I get this in my log

```
05-27 10:04:20.870: V/DownloadService(751): inside downloadservice dateString=213 20130523130035

05-27 10:04:20.890: V/DownloadService(751): inside downloadservice modificationdate=Sat Jul 23 07:30:35 AEDT 203
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you having a problem with incorrect value for `modificationdate` which was parsed from `dateString`?

Comment: yes the parsed date should be 23rd of May 2013, what I get is 23rd of July 203.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for the [String#substring(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method says:
***The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.***

And here is the problem you have: You're not using correctly the `String.substring()` method, because when invoking it, you receive another `String`, which contains a space as a first character, which is why the parser does a mistake.

Here's the fix you need:

```
String dateString = mFTPClient.getModificationTime(PDF_FILE_NAME_PS);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date modificationDate = 
     dateFormat.parse(dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf(" ") + 1));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
    "20130523130035" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" )
).toString()
```

> 2013-05-23T13:00:35

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Your input lacks an indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`. As such, this is *not* a moment, *not* a specific point on the timeline, but only a idea of potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours on the timeline.

```
String input = "213 20130523130035".split( " " )[1] ;  // Grab second piece of text from your input string, the 20130523130035 part.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2013-05-23T13:00:35

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).