# Java. Get date and time from string with milliseconds

Tags: java, date, time

I try to get date and time from string with milliseconds:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
 Date modifDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(ftpClient.getModificationTime(file_directory)));
 System.out.println(formatDate.format(modifDate));
```

But I have an exception in second line: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "213 20140601042221`. Where is my mistake and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you expecting `"213 20140601042221` to be parsed as a long?

Comment: I am guessing your `String` is not a `Long`. If your `String` is `213 20140601042221` should be split to produce 2 `Long`s.

Comment: Any chance this answers your question? [parsing a date string from FTPClient.getModificationTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764893/parsing-a-date-string-from-ftpclient-getmodificationtime)

Comment: `21320140601042221` is The value you want or May be just `20140601042221` use `split(" ")[1]` in `Long.parseLong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FTPClient.getModificationTime()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getModificationTime%28java.lang.String%29)

It returns `String` representing the last file modification time in `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` format.So if you are trying to parse it to `Long` than no use of that value.

You can do it like this.

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDhhmmss");//From FTPClient
    Date date=sd.parse("20140601042221");//Parse String to date
    SimpleDateFormat sd2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println(sd2.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well I am not sure what `213` is but `20140601042221` seems to be

```
YYYYmmddHHMMssSSS
```

this does not match what you have stated as

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Hint: use the `parse` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    String dateString=ftpClient.getModificationTime(file_directory));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date modificationDate = 
        dateFormat.parse(dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf(" ") + 1));
    SimpleDateFormat dateOutputFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println(""+dateOutputFormat.format(modificationDate));
```

Comment: This date format pattern is wrong

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tested on java SE application for this pattern, It gives output. "08.07.2014 12:06:02:658"

Comment: `20140601042221` is not `08.07.2014`

Comment: Are you saying "yyyyddMMHHmmssSS" ? this gives 20140807121235401 as output @ScaryWombat

Comment: `20140601042221` is not milliseconds, so `new Date(...` is wrong.  Should use `parse` method

Comment: I changed code, Is this correct? @ScaryWombat

Comment: No, new Date (long) takes a value which is milliseconds see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

Comment: I got your point, this would be the answer is it? @ScaryWombat

Comment: But it can't convert any date type isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56925/discussion-between-user3717646-and-scary-wombat).

Answer (score -1):

Try getting rid of the 213 and do something like:

SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYmmddHHMMssSSS");
System.out.println(formatDate.format(ftpClient.getModificationTime(file_directory)));

Comment: I think you mean `parse`